# Load content from external URL after Images/content loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, image-processing

I am trying load content from another url using pushstate/html5... The content I am trying to load has a big background image which takes time to load...

So when it animates fast full image seems to come up and slide in but then image reloads again...

I tried using

```
image preloader/
$(document).ready()
```

they all break the script and can't quite seem to figure out how to incoprate it here

```
    function goTo(href) {

    var left = $(window).width();
    $('#id').css("left", left);

    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        success: function (data) {

            var content = $(data).find('#id').html();

            // Windows Load Function
            $(window).load(function () {

                $("#id").html(content).animate({
                    left: '0',
                }, 'fast');

                var title = $('#id').find('h1').text();
                $('head').find('title').text(title);

            });
        }
    });
}

// check for support before we move ahead

if (typeof history.pushState !== "undefined") {
    var historyCount = 0;

    // On click of link Load content and animate
    $('.access a').live('click', function () {

        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        goTo(href);

        history.pushState(null, null, href);
        return false;
    });

    window.onpopstate = function () {
        if (historyCount) {
            goTo(document.location);
        }
        historyCount = historyCount + 1;
    };
}
```

Comment: What is the `image preloader/` line supposed to be? I suspect that, if nothing else, is gumming up the works; don't think JavaScript will accept that.

Comment: What is `href` in this case? it isn't external is it?

Comment: Ooops sorry that I was meant say I tried preloader method... I am not sure where  I put the preloader in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MonteCristo,

I think this is best addressed with [Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

In the code below, a Deferred object is passed to `goTo()` as a second argument, `animator`. This Deferred is resolved inside `goTo()` when all images with class `imgSelector` have sussessully loaded. On resolution of `animator` the animation fires and the page's title is changed.

Creating `animator` externally and passing it to `goTo()` allows this Deferred to be rejected from the scope where `goTo()` is called. This feature is included to inhibit the animation should another click or popstate event occur before the animation fires.

To make this work, you will need to serve each content page with a dummy off-screen foreground `<img>` with the same `src` as the problematic large background image and `class="critical"`. This is the easiest way to trigger an event when the background image loads.

```
$(function() {
    var $id = $("#id");
    var imgClass = 'critical';
    function goTo(href, animator) {
        $id.stop().css("left", $(window).width());
        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            success: function(data) {
                var deferreds = [];
                $id.html($(data).find('#id').html());
                $("img." + imgClass, $id).each(function() {
                    var d = new $.Deferred();
                    deferreds.push(d);
                    $(this).on('load error', function(){
                        d.resolve();
                    });
                });
                $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function() {
                    animator.resolve();
                });
                $.when(animator).done(function() {
                    $id.animate({
                        left: '0',
                    }, 'fast');
                    $('head title').text($('h1', $id).text());
                });
            }
        });
    }

    var historyCount = 0,
        animator = null;

    function getDeferred() {
        if(animator) {
            animator.reject();
        }
        animator = new $.Deferred();
        return animator;
    };

    if (typeof history.pushState !== "undefined") {
        $('.access a').live('click', function() {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            goTo(href, getDeferred());
            history.pushState(null, null, href);
            return false;
        });
        window.onpopstate = function() {
            if(historyCount) {
                goTo(document.location, getDeferred());
            }
            historyCount++;
        };
    }
});
```

*untested*

You may well need to debug and/or modify the code to get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need `$(window).load()` rather that `$(document).ready()` if you want to wait until after all the content and images have loaded.

So you probably want something like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('some element').css('background-image', 'url(big-background-image-file)');
});
```

Comment: this is what i did and not working? I have a feeling I am doing something wrong here? http://pastebin.com/BDM5ZNuV

Comment: @MonteCristo: To be honest, I have no idea what's going on in that pastebin. Can you fix up the indentation? I can't keep track of what is inside which functions...

Comment: @MonteCristo: You should put that in your question, it's much easier to read. Do you really have an element with `id="id"` in your HTML? That's what `#id` is referring to. I think you may have meant to use `#elements_actual_id` in those places. Also, I don't know what you're doing with that AJAX call. Whatever it is, I sort of doubt that it's what you want to do.

Comment: Ok I am just following this http://bit.ly/I5yfQR.... #id is just reference to an element in different url... What I am trying to achieve is pushSate() in HTML5. I am trying to load that content in to current page and animate them. That Content I am trying to pull has images... and they don't load same time as the text and messing up the animation...

Comment: @MonteCristo: OK, that guy's talking about doing something completely different, and unrelated to this. As a result, I wouldn't nest this code within that code at all. Try using the code I posted in the answer, just on its own, to see if it works. Obviously, you'll have to supply the name of the element and the path of the image in the indicated places.

Comment: ok I tried this following .load() as you mentioned `var href = $(this).attr('href');
  
  $('#section').load(href + "#content");` but its loading entire page rather than the sepcified div?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14766/discussion-between-dragoonwraith-and-montecristo)